# SQL Server Data Tools 15.5.0 - Script Component Validation Error

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssdt

When trying to use the script component in an SSIS dataflow I am getting a validation error meaning the script and my package will not work:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Validation error. Data Flow Task: Data Flow Task:
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.CannotCreateUserComponentException:
>   Cannot create user component class. Make sure there is one class
>   marked with SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute in your script.
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.VSTAComponentScriptingEngine.CreateScriptObjectHelper(Assembly
>   scriptAssembly)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.VSTAComponentScriptingEngine.GetScriptEntryPoint(String
>   versionGuid)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.CreateUserScriptInstance()       Package2.dtsx   0

I get this validation error on a brand new script component which builds perfectly fine. My package is targeting SQL Server 2012 and current versions are Visual Studio 2017 15.5.2 with SSDT 15.5.0. I also had the issue with 15.4.0 preview, when updating to 15.5.0 the script component did work initially and has since stopped working again.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a fix?

The only way I have been able to overcome this is to copy a script component from an existing package and then edit it.

I have reported [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155435/ssdt-1540-preview-script-component-source-error.html) but no response as yet.

Comment: There is a update available to SSDT (15.5.1) which fixes a couple of SSIS bugs, try upgrading to that. Also - are you trying to debug the package? If so, there is a known issue regarding debugging a package [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/changelog-for-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)

Comment: Why are there votes to close this question?! It is NOT unclear what is being asked.

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone added the question part